# Express ionic app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ionic-framework

Is it possible to turn the public folder of an ExpressJS web app into a client side ionic application that continues to connect to an express server hosted elsewhere? If so, is this a good practice?

Comment: The ionic app is independent, has a lot of dependencies and shit. You can however make the new ionic client side and connect to express.

Comment: So you have to start from scratch with a new ionic app to connect? How does connecting to external server files work?

Comment: Well yea; at least that's how I do it. The front (html & css) is different, maybe you have some similarities in the controller but that's it. You then fetch your resources from the same express back.

Comment: @yBrodsky Hmm interesting. If you could place some code showing your express code or tutorial in the answer section, that'd hep out a lot and I'll except it a the answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: I don't really have a code to show you. I have a browser app and a ionic app. Whenever I need to put something from the browser into the ionic I create the proper html for ionic (using their directives so it looks nice) and I create the controller. The controller code is almost the same. Then I have a resource which fetches the data, this is the same for the browser and the ionic app. I don't know, tell me what part of the code would be useful and I show you.